# Angular and OpenLayers, close-ups spawn on click

Tags: angular, openlayers

Exact output is shown on picture one, there should be only one map and clicking on it shouldn't spawn close-up copies below the actual map.

[image]

Maps spawn only if focus of the map has been changed and map itself was clicked. This weird behavior is not triggered from listener level, even if given section of code is empty, close-up spawns all the same, I believe it's matter of configuration. Close-up canvases spawn post app-root. Below is code of map.component.ts, map.component.scss and map.component.html
The last section is index.html containing scripts necessary for openlayers to work

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// @ts-ignore
import 'ol/ol.css';
import MVT from 'ol/format/MVT';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import VectorTileLayer from 'ol/layer/VectorTile';
import VectorTileSource from 'ol/source/VectorTile';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {Fill, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import {defaults} from 'ol/control';

const selectedCountry = new Style({
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(200,20,20,0.8)',
    width: 2,
  }),
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'rgba(200,20,20,0.4)',
  }),
});
const INITIAL_OPACITY = 1;
var selection: Dictionary<Feature<any>> = {};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  country = new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'gray',
      width: 1,
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(20,20,20,0.9)',
    }),
  });

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    const vtLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
      declutter: true,
      source: new VectorTileSource({
        maxZoom: 15,
        format: new MVT({
          idProperty: 'iso_a3',
        }),
        url:
          'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' +
          'ne:ne_10m_admin_0_countries@EPSG%3A900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf',
      }),
      style: this.country,
    });

    const map = new Map({
      layers: [vtLayer],
      target: 'map',
      pixelRatio: 1,
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2,
        multiWorld: false,

      }),
      controls : defaults({
        attribution : true,
        rotate: false
    }),
    });
    const selectionLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
      map: map,
      renderMode: 'vector',
      source: vtLayer.getSource(),
      style: function (feature: any) {
        if (feature.getId() in selection) {
          return selectedCountry;
        } else {
          return undefined
        }
      },
    });
    map.on(['click', 'singleclick', 'dblclick'], function (event: any) {
      vtLayer.getFeatures(event.pixel).then(function (features) {
        selection = {};
        if (!features.length) {
          selection = {};
          selectionLayer.changed();
          return;
        }
        const feature = features[0];
        if (!feature) {
          return;
        }
        const fid = feature.getId();
        // add selected feature to lookup
        if (fid){
          selection[fid] = feature;
        }
        selectionLayer.changed();
      });
  });
  }
}
interface Dictionary<T> {
  [Key: string]: T;
}
```

```css
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height:55rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MapFront</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep"></script>
  <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.2.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is an old bug https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/10879 which can also bee seen in the version 6.3.1 example if you scroll down the page after clicking https://openlayers.org/en/v6.3.1/examples/vector-tile-selection.html  It is fixed in later versions.

Comment: I've raised it to current version and it seems problem has been solved, thank you very much Mike.